# I need to validate that the start date is less than the end date in Yii2 with the help of JSON

Tags: json, date, yii2-advanced-app

These are the image one image are of view file on which date is showing.
Here date is not validated it picks the date even before the start date.
I also attached the coding screenshot please has a look and let me the suitable answer.

[image]

Comment: What you have tried so for? what should I see in this image:) share some code with us.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate it in the model, I assume, that it is `$courseTest`
with the following rule:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        ['setting_test_attempt_time', function($attribute, $params) {
            $decoded = json_decode($this->$attribute, true);
            if ($decoded['from'] > $decoded['to']) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'The From date must be less than To');
            }
        }]
    ];
}
```